# Domain count in QC

Tags: php, rest, api

How to resolve the error, which is appearing while getting the Quality Center domain count using API. Below is the code for fetching QC domains. This code is working fine in one machine, but giving below error on server.

```
<?php
 $qc = curl_init();
 //create a cookie file
 $ckfile = "";
 //set URL and other appropriate options
 curl_setopt($qc, CURLOPT_URL, "http://myserver/qcbin/rest/is-authenticated");
 curl_setopt($qc, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
 curl_setopt($qc, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
 curl_setopt($qc, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 //grab the URL and pass it to the browser
 $result = curl_exec($qc);
 $response = curl_getinfo($qc);

 if($response['http_code'] == "401")
  {
        $url = "http://myserver/qcbin/authentication-point/authenticate";
        $credentials = "USER:PSWD";
        $headers = array("GET /HTTP/1.1","Authorization: Basic ". base64_encode($credentials));
        curl_setopt($qc, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($qc, CURLOPT_HTTPGET,1); 
        curl_setopt($qc, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        //Set the cookie
        curl_setopt($qc, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile);
        curl_setopt($qc, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $result = curl_exec($qc);
        $response = curl_getinfo($qc);

        if($response['http_code'] == '200')
        {
         $domain_url = "http://myserver/qcbin/rest/domains";
         curl_setopt($qc, CURLOPT_URL, $domain_url);
         curl_setopt($qc, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
         curl_setopt($qc, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
         curl_setopt($qc, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
         $domain_data = curl_exec($qc);

         $domains = new SimpleXMLElement($domain_data);
         $result = $domains->xpath('//Domain');
         $domain_xml = simplexml_load_string($domain_data);
         $domain_count = count($domain_xml->xpath('//Domain'));
         echo $domain_count;  
        }
    curl_close($qc);
?>
```

Below is the error

> Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 10: parser
>   error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: hr line 8 and body in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\metrisi\batch\getDefTest.php on line 39
>
> Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct():  in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\metrisi\batch\getDefTest.php on line 39
>
> Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): ^ in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\metrisi\batch\getDefTest.php on line 39
>
> Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 11: parser
>   error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: body line 6 and html in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\metrisi\batch\getDefTest.php on line 39
>
> Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct():  in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\metrisi\batch\getDefTest.php on line 39
>
> Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): ^ in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\metrisi\batch\getDefTest.php on line 39
>
> Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 12: parser
>   error : Premature end of data in tag html line 1 in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\metrisi\batch\getDefTest.php on line 39
>
> Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\metrisi\batch\getDefTest.php on line 39
>
> Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): ^ in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\metrisi\batch\getDefTest.php on line 39
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: String could not be parsed as XML in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\metrisi\batch\getDefTest.php:39 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\metrisi\batch\getDefTest.php(39):
>   SimpleXMLElement->__construct('\n\n<...') #1 {main} thrown
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\metrisi\batch\getDefTest.php on line 39

Comment: Start by verifying that the input data is the same on both servers - maybe your cURL request failed or returned a different result than the one you expected.

Comment: Is this `http://myserver` actually accessible from internet or is it your VHost address?

Comment: Yes I verified the data. Also I replaced the server IP with myserver.

Comment: _“Opening and ending tag mismatch: hr line 8 and body”_ - sounds like you are trying to parse HTML as XML here, and it trips up on stuff like `<hr>` with no closing tag …? With `simplexml_load_string` you can pass LIBXML options as third parameter, try if `LIBXML_NOERROR` changes anything. (Why are you loading `$domain_data` with `new SimpleXMLElement` _and_ `simplexml_load_string` btw.? And `$result = $domains->xpath('//Domain');` doesn’t seem to get used anywhere.)

Comment: @misorude Let me tell you, how Quality Center display the data. Actually when we  extract the domains, it displays the data in xml, as given below:

  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
- <Domains>
  <Domain Name="Domain01" /> 
  </Domains>